# Word document loads incredibly slow

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have a word document (286kb) which takes almost 2 min to load.  The document contains a large number of excel objects (as links from the same workbook).

This is what I've tried:

- Remove the "old" template and replaced it with the "normal template"
- Changed the settings in word, such that it does not automatically
  update the links, when documents are loaded.

Is there someway I can bring the load time down?

Comment: Have you verified all links are valid? A lot of links will slow it down some, but broken ones can cause major issues.

Answer (score 1):

Word is likely to *check* the links regardless of the setting of "automatically update links".

2 things you can at least try:

- Ensure that you open the linked Excel workbook(s) before you open the
  Word document. This should prevent Word from closing/re-opening the
  workbooks as it updates the links.
- Set/modify a DelayOleSrvParseDisplayName registry entry and
  NoActivateOleLinkObjAtOpen registry entry to modify the global
  behaviour, as described [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/970154) .

FWIW there is also some code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838569/vba-list-of-filepaths-of-linked-objects-in-document) intended to remove links from a .docx file before opening it in Word. But it's intended for a much more extreme scenario where the document is taking a lot longer to open.